# Background image not being displayed in input box

Tags: html, css

I dont know why this is not working. I have already had a look and can't find any solution.

See it [LIVE HERE](http://79.170.40.182/kingsley-test.co.uk/kingsley%209.9.2016/kingsley-new/refer.php).

The two input boxes in the banner have background images attached but they are not showing.

Comment: +1 when asking question it is advisable to include a minimal, verifiable example example as  a snippet here itself (external links only if needed to support the question)... so that guys who see the question later on when faced with the same issue, can figure it out easily (external links can expire too!)

Answer (score 1):

Change `background: transparent;` to `background-color: transparent;`.

**Explaination:**

```
.jobs-inp {
    background-image: url(images/magnify-icon.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
    padding-left: 15px;
    background: transparent;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Interstate-Regular;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid white;
    height: 40px;
    width: 25%;
}
```

`background: transparent;` overrides all background properties before, because `background` is a shorthand for all properties.

Comment: Legend... Thanks for that